# Is it better to use multiple NSTimers or put all code into one?

Tags: cocoa, nstimer

I am working in Xcode4 and in a project I had been using three different NSTimers for organizational purposes, but I realized that the timers were identical, except for the names, so it would be easy to have all three timers merged into just one. Which would be better coding for my project, the three separate timers dividing the code, or just the one with all the code in it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, timers don't have code "in" them, but rather invoke methods when the timer "ticks".  You can easily have one timer invoke a "master" method that in turn invokes several subsidiary methods, so the individual methods can remain associated with the classes that they naturally "belong" to.  Or three separate timers.  Whatever is the most natural "division of labor".  The performance/efficiency difference of 3 timers vs 1 is not worth worrying about -- it's more about clarity of code structure.

Comment: That reads a lot like an answer rather than a comment, @HotLicks.

Answer (score 2):

There can be significant energy impacts of having multiple timers if they fire out of sync with each other. Modern CPUs try to sleep as much as they can, and allowing them to sleep periodically for even a few milliseconds at a time can substantially improve battery life. If you have timers that go off close together, but not quite at the same time, then the system has fewer opportunities to sleep. I recommend Session 704 (Building Efficient OS X Apps) and Session 712 (Energy Best Practices) from [WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) which discusses this at length and how you can improve your code. Apple has spent significant effort recently in improving how timers are managed and encouraging developers to better batch their timers together.

This isn't a reason to add significant complexity to your code, and @HotLicks and @GerdK are correct that code simplicity often trumps other concerns, but the costs should not be ignored, especially on modern CPUs and high frequency timers.

Note that there are some new NSTimer options that can help you get the benefits of batched timers without actually restructuring your code in the latest OSes. See the above videos for more on that (still under NDA, so I can't go into the details here).

Answer (score 0):

Whichever method makes your code easier to understand.